# Having some issues making specific line charts in Excel

Tags: charts, microsoft-excel-2013

I need to pass a graph to excel and I'm failing to do so. I have no idea where to fix it.

Basically I already have one on Matlab, but I want to remake it from excel to make it look better. Here is the original one:

[image: x]

This is how my Excel graph currently looks like alongside with it's current data for the graph:

[image: x]

I've already tried messing around to fix it as well as consulting other websites, but can't seem to find anything that will help. Does anyone have an idea how I can make this happen?

Edit: as requested, here are the functions for each series:

=SERIES("Bad",{0,10,20,30,40,50,60},Sheet1!$N$3:$N$21,1)

=SERIES("Average",{0,10,20,30,40,50,60},Sheet1!$O$3:$O$21,2)

=SERIES("Good",{0,10,20,30,40,50,60},Sheet1!$P$3:$P$21,3)

Comment: It would be useful if we could see the function of the chart series as that is where your problem is.  Click on one of the series and you should see something like this in your function bar =SERIES(,Sheet1!$D$3:$D$9,Sheet1!$E$3:$E$9,1).  My x axis is in column D and my data is in columns E-G and it looks fine.

Comment: @gtwebb I edited the post to add them. But to be honest, I have no idea what it means...

Answer (score 0):

You have selected too many rows for the chart. You only need to select the rows with data. Otherwise, the empty rows will be plotted as empty space and the chart will be compressed.

The screenshot is an XY chart with column A as the X values. You can also use a line chart with column A as the category.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the range of cells containing the data into a Table (Insert ribbon, Table).  That way, the references in the chart will be to the table columns. The table will automatically expand as you type or paste in new rows (or even columns).